# Unreal Building for Quest 2 : rungraddle.bat error

Tags: android, error-handling, unreal-engine4, quest, unrealscript

[The the screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMYqn.png)

So i have been trying to build for the quest 2 and i cant seem to fix this error forever. I need help fixing this error or im goin to loose my mind

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Usually building Unreal projects for Android, in case there are issues, it's good to fully uninstall any Android related things, remove any related environment variable, and follow again the instructions on installing Android Studio from the official Unreal documentation. They specify which versions of the SDK and NDK you should install for which engine version.